# how to find how java's methods are written on itellj?

Tags: java, api, methods

yesterday my tutor showed me a keyboard shotcut that showed me how a java package code was written. For example, he held his cursor of the implementation of a listiterator in my program and from their he brought up the class for listiterator from java and it showed how all the methods were written.

How do you do this??

Comment: You can `Ctrl`-click an identifier (variable name, method name, etc), and intellij will jump to either where it was declared (if clicked in the "wild"), or it will show you usages of the identifier if you're already clicking where it was declared

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean you want to jump to the declaration. You can press control and left mouse click. Also, there is a shortcut which is Goto | Declaration (Ctrl+B) and you might be interested in Goto | Back (Alt+Back) and Search | Find Usages Popup (Ctrl+Alt+F7)